# Disable jquery function for screen size. works on reload, but not on resize

Tags: jquery, media-queries, responsive

```
<script>
var smallScreen = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    if($(window).width() > 770) {
        smallScreen = true;
    }
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() > 770) {
        smallScreen = true;
    } else {
        smallScreen = false;
    }
});
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
</script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
        if(smallScreen) {
            $('#image-gallery').lightSlider({
                gallery:true,
                mode:'fade',
                item:1,
                thumbItem:5,
                slideMargin: 0,
                speed:500,
                auto:false,
                loop:true,
                thumbMargin:20,
                enableDrag:false,
                onSliderLoad: function() {
                    $('#image-gallery').removeClass('cS-hidden');
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

the first script determines if the screen size is above or below 770 px. Then i choose to run the lightslider gallery function accordingly. When reloading the page, the function works. I can't figure out how to get the function to work when the user resizes the page.

Answer (score 0):

Make light slider initialization as function, light slider only work after reload because it just execute after document ready, you must execute after window resize too.

```
<script>

   $(window).resize(function() {
      if($(window).width() > 770) {
         initLightSlider();
      }else{
         //destroy light slider here if you want destroy when windows <= 770
      }
   });

   $(document).ready(function() {
        if($(window).width() > 770) {
            initLightSlider();
        }
   });

   function initLightSlider(){
       //you must destroy plugin first here, if plugin already initialization
       $('#image-gallery').lightSlider({
            gallery:true,
            mode:'fade',
            item:1,
            thumbItem:5,
            slideMargin: 0,
            speed:500,
            auto:false,
            loop:true,
            thumbMargin:20,
            enableDrag:false,
            onSliderLoad: function() {
                $('#image-gallery').removeClass('cS-hidden');
            }  
        });     
   }
</script>
```

call this function

> initLightSlider();

after window resize or page loaded with some condition

Comment: When the page loads, the slideshow doesn't appear until the screen is resized. what is happening?

Comment: also, when i do resize the function, the thumbnails for the slideshow get messed up and there's like 50 of the thumbnails stacked on top of eachother.

Comment: when page loaded it have screen width more than 770?